# Recommended REST API design for transferring amount

Tags: web-development, rest, api-design

I want to design a REST API given the following data model :

Accounts

```
UserId |  Balance 

user1  |   500
user2  |   200
```

And given the following Ui that must use the REST service for it's operation for a transfer of funds.

[image]

What would be the best way of designing the api for this data model that must also support the transfer UI action?

(URL, HTTP method , body ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `POST` as method.

The endpoint would be `/api/controllerName/Transfer`

And the body would look like this

```
{
    "from": 123,
    "to": 456,
    "amount": 789
}
```

`from` and `to`being user id's, or other identification for the user.

`amount` being your amount.

Comment: and just hope floats are good for monetary values

Comment: To be clear, in a RESTful architecture, "Transfer" in this case is a noun.  You are posting a transfer, which is a resource in its own right and which can later be viewed, etc. This is probably what you want anyway, I'm just clarifying because "transfer" can also be a verb.  In fact, I'd probably clarify the API more by making the endpoint be '/api/transfers'

Comment: @Ewan so far we've only seen integers discussed.

Comment: Javascript and JSON don't do integers.

Comment: @Ewan isn't that kind of out of context ?

Comment: in the context of designing a rest interface to transfer money. not having it transfer the wrong amount is quite important. If the OP is an interview question, my follow up would be "what if the transfer is for 50bil pounds?" given the lack of support, you would be better off using strings

Comment: The main question is how to design the api, not what types he should use. I'm pretty sure his models / prerequisites for them are already stated somewhere. I just added numbers as an example.